# Totally transfer VSCode settings from one Mac to another

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode is wonderful but it takes a little careful setting-up.

There are numerous secret tips to follow, example

[How to turn off "matching" highlighting in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775406/how-to-turn-off-matching-highlighting-in-vs-code/45640244#45640244)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59225110/294884

and so on.

If I have everything "just right" on Mac A, how can I perfectly transfer all the detail to Macs B, C, and D?

For that matter, how could one transfer their VSCode settings to a Windows machine from a Mac?

## Note, now includes in VSCode from 2021...

Another amazing new feature added to VSCode:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the vscode extension [Setting Sync](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Shan.code-settings-sync). It uses github to sync everything up, it should be platform agnostic and works like a charm.